# FancyBox refreshing on every click

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am trying to create a form with fancy box and unfortuantely even though it display the input elements and correct markup, clicking on anything in the form causes the fancybox to refresh.  What am I missing to disable the click event bubble so you can actually get into a text input box or select form the selectoptions without the fancy box refreshing?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var box = $("#show_mailing_list_signup");


        box.fancybox({
            'showCloseButton': true,
            'scrolling': 'no',
            'titleShow': false,
            'beforeLoad': function() {
                return !hideMailList();
            },
            'afterLoad': function() {

                $('#disableSignup').click(function() {
                    setCookie("hideSignup", true, 365);
                    $.fancybox.close();
                    return false;
                });

                $("#send_form").click(function() {

                    return false;
                });


            }
        }).click();
    });


<div id="show_mailing_list_signup">
        <form id="mailinglistForm" method="post">
            <h2>Header</h2>
            <label for="name">* Name </label>
            <p>
                <input name="fname" type="text" id="name" minlength="4" maxlength="15" />
            </p>
            <br />
            <label for="email">* Email </label>
            <p>
                <input name="email" type="text" id="email" />
            </p>
            <br />
            <label for="state">Pick your favorite school</label>
            <p>
                <select id="state">
                    <option>NY</option>
                    <option>IL</option>
                </select>
                <select id="city">
                    <option>Schenectedy</option>
                    <option>Fishkill</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input id="schoolSearch" type="text"/>
            </p>

            <%--default to the most select school--%>
            <p style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <input value="Join Now" type="button" name="send_form" id="send_form" />
            </p>

        </form>
        <p class="details">blah</p>
        <a href="#" id="disableSignup">don't show again</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do this

```
var box = $("#show_mailing_list_signup");
    box.fancybox().click()
```

the element `<div id="show_mailing_list_signup">` (which contains the form you open in fancybox) becomes the ***trigger*** and the ***target*** of fancybox so anything you `click` inside that container will trigger fancybox over and over again.

Change the selector to something else to target your form like

```
var box = $(".fancybox");
    box.fancybox({
        // API options here
    }).click();
```

**NOTE**: you still need to have an html element (usually a link) with `class="fancybox"` to target your `form` like :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#show_mailing_list_signup"></a>
```