# Fancybox is not working with specific selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I use this code but it is not working...

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#welcomePopup').fancybox();              
        });
```

but another code is working fine like

```
$.fancybox({
                    'padding': 5,
                    'width': 625,
                    'height': 450,
                    'content': $("#welcomePopup").html()
                });
```

I would like to use first approach because the second one duplicate HTML.

Any clue?

Comment: check your html for multiple 'welcomePopup' ids

Comment: you are falling in this scenario http://stackoverflow.com/a/19507562/1055987

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#welcomePopup').fancybox();              
});
```

**only** binds the selector `#welcomePopup` to fancybox but it doesn't open it. You still need to `click` on that selector to open fancybox.

A normal scenario for the code above is

```
<a id="welcomePopup" href="{your target content}">open fancybox</a>
```

where `#welcomePopup` is the fancybox **trigger**

On the other hand, if the contents of `#welcomePopup` is what you want to show as fancybox content (`#welcomePopup` is the fancybox **target**), then you need another selector to act as the trigger.

The normal approach for this second scenario would be :

html

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#welcomePopup">open welcome pop up in fancybox</a>
<div style="display: none;" id="welcomePopup">
    <h1>fancybox content</h1>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();              
});
```

Last, if you want to open fancybox without a trigger AND on page load, then either of these will do the trick

```
$.fancybox({
    'padding': 5,
    'width': 625,
    'height': 450,
    'href': "#welcomePopup"
});
```

or

```
$.fancybox("#welcomePopup",{
    'padding': 5,
    'width': 625,
    'height': 450
});
```

Comment: Yeah... But my father didn't give me the ability to resolve coding issues... In that sense I am a simple human. :) Thank you for the help, bro!